# Why did ISRO require additional tracking ships in the South Pacific for its MOM mission?

Tags: isro, pslv, mars-orbiter-mission, ground-station, tracking

[ISRO](http://www.isro.org/) (Indian Space Research Organisation) so far never before used additional marine vessels to help track their launch vehicles, as an extension to the [Indian Deep Space Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Deep_Space_Network) (IDSN). So why did it require additional tracking stations in the South Pacific for the launch of the [PSLV C25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle#PSLV_flight_C25) (Polar Satellite Launch Vehicle) on its [Magalyaan / Mars Orbiter Mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Orbiter_Mission) (MOM)?

Wikipedia writes to say about the [MOM tracking and command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Orbiter_Mission#Tracking_and_command):

> The [Indian Space Research Organisation Telemetry, Tracking and Command
>   Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Space_Research_Organisation_Telemetry,_Tracking_and_Command_Network) performed navigation and tracking operations for the launch
>   with ground stations at Sriharikota, Port Blair, Brunei and Biak in
>   Indonesia, and after the spacecraft's apogee becomes more than
>   100,000 km, two large 18-metre and 32-metre diameter antennas of the
>   [Indian Deep Space Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Deep_Space_Network) will be utilised.
>
> NASA's Deep Space
>   Network will provide position data through its three stations located
>   in Canberra, Madrid and Goldstone on the U.S. West Coast during the
>   non-visible period of ISRO's network. Additional monitoring is
>   provided by technicians on board two leased ships from [Shipping
>   Corporation of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shipping_Corporation_of_India), SCI Nalanda and SCI Yamuna which are currently
>   in position in the South Pacific near Fiji.

How did they track their previous launchers, like e.g. [Chandrayaan-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrayaan-1), without these additional tracking stations, and why was this extension to the IDSN necessary for Magalyaan, if they already used NASA's [Deep Space Network](http://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/dsn/) with facilities in Canberra, Australia?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]
                                                   <sup>ISRO's MOM lifting off (credit [Universe Today](http://www.universetoday.com/106127/indias-first-mars-mission-launches-flawlessly-on-historic-journey-to-the-red-planet/)).</sup>

What it comes down to is that this launch went over the ocean - thereby creating a need for man-made buoyant pieces of steel equipped with tracking devices to collect telemetry data. It's ground track looked like this:

[image]
                                                   <sup>MOM's ground track (credit [SpaceFlight101](http://www.spaceflight101.com/pslv-mom-ascent-data.html)).</sup>

As you can see, much of the track was over water, in places where ISRO didn't have access to tracking stations. [I'm looking for the ground track of Chandrayaan-1](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/what-was-chandrayaan-1s-ground-track), but so far haven't been able to find it. I'm willing to bet, though, that either:

- The ground track was slightly different, perhaps going more directly over Australia, or
- The launch vehicle was designed in such a way for that mission as to negate the need for continued tracking.

All in all, the extra ships were needed because of the way MOM's ground track was - right over an ocean.