# What was Chandrayaan-1's ground track?

Tags: tracking, isro, ground-track, chandrayaan-spacecraft

I was looking for a map of Chandrayaan-1's ground track, but I wasn't able to find one. I'm looking for something like this:

[image]
                                                   <sup>MOM's ground track (credit [SpaceFlight101](http://www.spaceflight101.com/pslv-mom-ascent-data.html)).</sup>

Does anyone know what the ground track looked like?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question? Are you asking for the ground track of the launch profile?

Comment: You need to specify the time span you want the ground track to be. Because of orbit pertubations the ground track changes over time. Not mention that the earth is rotating 15 deg a hour so the groundtrak changes respective to ground. You can install a free copy of STK and plot it on your own for your specific problem.